# Docker с нуля для чайника

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Изучаю Docker и не много разобрался могу создать контейнер, свой image и так же удалять их... но полного понимания нет. С помощью docker хотел запустить несколько сайтов с разными версиями php

Помогите ответить на мои вопросы:

1. При создании контейнеров нужно каждому контейнеру задавать свой порт?
   Для примера:
   Создаю три контейнера

   docker run -d -p 87:80 site:v1

   docker run -d -p 88:80 site:v2

   docker run -d -p 89:80 site:v3

Или же для каждого контейнера можно не указывать порт

```
docker run -d site:v1

docker run -d site:v2

docker run -d site:v3
```

Если нужно указывать порты то как получается для 80 и 3306 портов надо будет указывать каждому контейнеру нужно будет указывать два своих порта, а если три порта используется то соответственно каждому три порта?

2. Хочу для всех своих сайтов использовать свои NS записи вопрос как правильно поднять DNS в docker? Его нужно поднимать в каждом контейнере так же как и apache?
3. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно задать размеры дискового пространства к примеру для сайта хочу выделить место в 5Гб и не хочу что бы вышло за пределы этих размеров.
4. Подскажите пожалуйста для чего нужен docker-compose? Правильно ли я понимаю что с его помощью собираются разные image для контейнера?

Вопросы возможно для Вас глупые, но в docker я новичок и разбираюсь с ним.

Всё крутится у меня на ОС Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: @Глеб как его по другому сформулировать и на какой конкретно проблеме его сфокусировать если всё что я спросил для меня это как один вопрос и одна проблема

Comment: Не знаю, как сформулировать, но по правилам сайта такие вопросы не очень подходят. Есть даже такая тревога "Необходимо конкретизировать" — как раз на этот случай. Просто дело в том, что человеку, который придет на ваш вопрос из поиска будет не очень удобно искать ответ.

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Скажите пожалуйста в чём вопросы не связаны друг с другом? Я задаю вопросы по docker и не понимаю зачем плодить миллион тем когда успешно всё можно поместить в одной. Или Вы просто не знаете что ответить и отвечаете хоть что то?

Comment: 0. вообще здесь мы создаём базу знаний, а не техподдержку/faq/место-чтобы-пообщаться и т.д. и т.п. 1. чтобы ответы на вопросы были полезными не только задающему, но и многим другим, каждый вопрос должен задаваться отдельно. конечно, вопрос может содержать и подвопросы, но только если они уж очень тесно взаимосвязаны. 2. связаны ваши вопросы только тем фактом, что их задаёт один и тот же человек. 3. дальнешее обсуждение данной темы предлагаю вести на мете. вы тут не новичок, правила, надеюсь, знаете хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Я и сам начинающий докерист, но попробую ответить.

> 1. При создании контейнеров нужно каждому контейнеру задавать свой порт?

А как вы иначе будете обращаться к php на этих контейнерах с вашей хост-машины - по одному и тому же порту? Каждый из них должен быть виден [на разных портах хост машины](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819934/running-multiple-services-on-same-port-in-docker-compose), чтобы вы могли к ним раздельно обращаться. Так что да, нужно будет сделать маппинг 80 порта каждого из контейнеров на разные порты хост машины, как у вас в коде и сделано.

> Если нужно указывать порты то как получается для 80 и 3306 портов надо будет указывать каждому контейнеру нужно будет указывать два своих порта, а если три порта используется то соответственно каждому три порта?

Да, именно так. В параметрах вызова докера можно указать сколько угодно параметров `-p` с маппингом портов, например для двух маппингов:

```
docker run -d -p 87:80 -p 3306:3306 site:v1
```

> 2. Хочу для всех своих сайтов использовать свои NS записи вопрос как правильно поднять DNS в docker? Его нужно поднимать в каждом контейнере так же как и apache?

`DNS` сервер не нужно поднимать в каждом контейнере. А если у вас есть доступ к какому-то готовому `DNS` серверу, то ни в одном контейнере не нужно поднимать, можете на том доступном вам `DNS` сервере всё прописать. В общем, достаточно одного `DNS` сервера, на котором вы пропишете все нужные записи и пропишете везде где нужно обращения к этому `DNS` серверу.

`Apache` поднимают на каждом сервере только потому, что `PHP` с ним сильно интегрирован и его скорее всего нельзя установить отдельно от апача. В теории можно было бы иметь один веб-сервер, который бы обслуживал всё, что вам нужно, но сам веб-сервер настолько небольшой и настолько интегрированный с конкретным движком (например, `PHP`), что проще и удобнее поднимать в каждом контейнере свой веб-сайт.

А вот с `DNS` всё по-другому и нет нужды делать в каждом контейнере свой `DNS` сервер. Хотя в теории вы могли бы сделать отдельные `DNS` сервера и объединить их потом в общую иерархию, но обычно так никто не делает, достаточно одного `DNS` сервера на организацию (плюс его копия/резерв, если сетка серьёзная).

> 3. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно задать размеры дискового пространства к примеру для сайта хочу выделить место в 5Гб и не хочу что бы вышло за пределы этих размеров.

```
--storage-opt size=5G
```

Сейчас в докер такая опция добавлена, но это работает вроде бы [не на любой дисковой системе](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-storage-driver-options-per-container).

> 4. Подскажите пожалуйста для чего нужен docker-compose? Правильно ли я понимаю что с его помощью собираются разные image для контейнера?

Он позволяет согласованно запускать несколько контейнеров. Не всё можно сделать в рамках одного контейнера. Например, в одном контейнере у вас БД, в другом веб-сайт, в третьем `message queue` какая-нибудь. И вы не хотите их собирать в один контейнер, хотите иметь возможность администрировать и перезапускать их по отдельности. А может и масштабировать - добавлять в конфигурацию дополнительные сервера БД, например, или потом захотите добавить ещё какой-то сервис, не останавливая остальные т.п. Докер-композ позволяет согласованно настроить и запустить контейнеры в нужном вам сочетании и в нужном порядке. Буквально жмёте одну кнопку - и у вас запустились все нужные контейнеры. То есть это следующий уровень абстракции сверху над отдельными контейнерами.

Comment: Интересно, кто минус поставил. Я готов к критике, но ведь ничего не объясняют. )

Comment: Спасибо большое. Есть теперь хоть практически окончательное понимание как работает всё в docker. Пойду теперь ломать тестовый сервак =)